PDF content extraction only from a certain region
I am trying to extract the content of the PDF without its header or footer, So I tried noting the length between the corner edge and the region till when I need the content I used these points as crop points and extracted content inside uncropped region, I used pdfplumber for this it was working great but found out that my code is not working on the pdf which has application as LaTeX or Tex etc... generally PDF not created from acrobat I want to make it work for all pdfs
This is what I tried:
def extract_first_lines_for_HTML(pdf_path):
extracted_data = []
non_extracted_data = []
with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
    for page_number in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        page = pdf.pages[page_number]
        # print(page_number)

        # Adjust the crop box to exclude headers and footers
        crop_box = (left, top, page.width - int(right), page.height - int(bottom))  # Adjust margins as needed
        page_crop = page.within_bbox(crop_box)

        page_text = page_crop.extract_text(x_tolerance=1.5, y_tolerance=3.8)

Here left, top, right and bottom are the cropping points taken in points
if I try this on pdf produced from LaTeX it shows error as
ValueError: Bounding box (20, 30, 411.98, 617.9939999999999) is not fully within parent page bounding box (81.72, 97.2, 513.7, 745.194)
I tried calculating with parent page bounding box too, still not working can anyone help me with this Please...….!

no what I am trying to do is to read the content of pdf from all pages but I don't want to read the header or footer that's it
